# How to properly scale a TikZ/PGF picture which has a `\begin{axis}...\end{axis}`

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, scaling

Applying a scale option to a TikZ picture works great. It keeps the text the proper size and scales everything else.  I would like to have the same behavior when using a `\begin{axis}...\end{axis}`.

Consider the following in which the first graphic does not use the `{axis}` environment. Changing the scale works great. However, try changing the scale option of the second `\begin{tikzpicture}` to `scale=1.5`. This has the effect that the x and y axis labels are moved far away form the axis.

Furthermore, I can see no apparent change in the scale option applied to `\begin{axis}`.  I don't see any error messages complaining about it, so it must be a valid option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
\draw [->][gray, thin](-3,0) -- (3,0)
    node[blue, right] {$x$}; 

\draw [->][gray, thin] (0,-3) -- (0,3)
    node[blue, above] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
\begin{axis}[scale=1.5 % Has no effect
    minor tick num=0, 
    axis y line=center, 
    axis x line=middle, 
    xmin=-3,
    xmax=3, 
    ymin=-3,
    ymax=3,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$
    ]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Also, one other minor nit-pick now that I posted this: How do I got about getting the x,y labels within `{axis}` to be to the right and on top as in the first example?

Comment: Seeing you posted a new question saying you didn't get a good answer to this one: Maybe you could clarify what it is exactly you're trying to achieve here? If the question is "How do I make a PGFplots larger without changing line widths and font sizes?", then the answer is given below: Use `width`and `height` (or the development version's `scale` option). If the question is "How do I scale a `tikzpicture` which, among other things, contains a PGFplots axis, while keeping line widths and font sizes", then the answer is: You can't; the `axis` environment is jus too complex for this.

Comment: @Jake: Sorry, I did not mean to imply that the postings here not good. They are extremely helpful, I just have to wait until these changes make it to the released versions. The other question has similar behavior but without the `scale` adjustment - I referenced this question in case the problem is related.

Comment: Related Question: [Pgfplots axis labes misplaced (half page away from the grid)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509988/4301).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to adjust the size of a plot without changing the text size, you should use the `width` and `height` options. There is no scale option for this, unfortunately: You'll have to multiply the width and height yourself.

The development version contains the options `x post scale` and `y post scale` (which are marked `EXPERIMENTAL` in the source code, but seem to work fine). This will in effect increase the `width` and `height` of the plot, so it's not really just scaled: Depending on whether you increase or decrease the size of the plot, you will get more or less tick lines. This is a sensible thing, I believe, but maybe not what you need?

To install the development version using TeXLive, you can use the command
`sudo -i tlmgr update pgfplots --repository http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/2010`

You can then define a new `scale` style that sets all `post scale` options to the same value simultaneously:

```
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/scale/.style={
  x post scale=#1,
  y post scale=#1,
  z post scale=#1}
}
```

In order to place the `x label` and `y label` at the ends of the axes, you can use the following options:

```
xlabel style={at={(current axis.right of origin)}, xshift=1.5ex, anchor=center},
ylabel style={at={(current axis.above origin)}, yshift=1.5ex, anchor=center}
```

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/scale/.style={
  x post scale=#1,
  y post scale=#1,
  z post scale=#1}
}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/axis labels at tip/.style={
    xlabel style={at={(current axis.right of origin)}, xshift=1.5ex, anchor=center},
    ylabel style={at={(current axis.above origin)}, yshift=1.5ex, anchor=center}}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis y line=center, axis x line=middle, xmin=-3, xmax=3, ymin=-3, ymax=3, xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    axis labels at tip
    ]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale=0.6,
    axis y line=center, axis x line=middle, xmin=-3, xmax=3, ymin=-3, ymax=3, xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    axis labels at tip
    ]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: scaled pgfplots plot]

Comment: I am getting an `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/x post scale' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`. I had done a complete update about 3 weeks ago so should have the latest.  The log file lists `pgfplots 2010/07/14 Version 1.4.1`. Is there a later version?

Comment: @Peter: Oh yes, sorry, it's only been added to the development version. I'll change the answer to reflect this.

Comment: thanks for the investigation with that style. I'll include it in pgfplots for the moment as this appears to be a bug.

Comment: This now seems to be working as advertised with TeXLive2011.